# angular router navigateByUrl doesn't work after using location.go

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a form. When the user starts typing it is automatically saved and an id is returned. I use this id to update the url.

So before we start typing, the url is /arende and the modell behind the form is instantiated empty. After the first save has been made and an id has been returned the url is updated to /arende/666 where 666 is the id by using location.go().

The problem occurs when I want to "reset" the form, I want to navigate back to /arende and by doing that, reset the modell.

This doesnt work, navigateByUrl doesnt seem to do anything at this point. If I open my browser with an id already in the url i.e /arende/123 and then press navigateByUrl it works, but not after using location.go.

The stackblitz below has a few buttons in it that simulate different things.
The first button resets the form just for this demo.

The second button simulates a change in the form, i.e it changes the url by using location.go to /arende/666.

The third button is the button I would like to get like to get working, so after using the second button I would like to use this third button to do a real navigation to /arende to reset the form and model.

The fourth button is just a demonstration on how it would look if I would use navigateByUrl instead of location.go, it fetches the object and shows loaders when the user changes the form which is unacceptable.

The fifth button is the current temporary solution where I have a special id called "new" which I navigate to after I have clicked location.go. This triggers a navigation but is interrupted when it senses the "new" keyword and does another navigateByUrl to /arende.

So to sum it up. I would like to do a unnoticable change of the url to /arende/666 while the user is typing in the form. And later on I would like to reset the form by doing a navigation to /arende.

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwknbk

App component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location
  ){}

  ngOnInit(){

  }

  locationgo(){
    let url = this.router.createUrlTree(['arende/666']).toString();
    this.location.go(url);
  }

  navigate(){
    console.log('this.router.navigateByUrl("/arende")');
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/arende");
  }

  navigateWithLoader(){
    console.log('this.router.navigateByUrl("/arende/666")');
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/arende/666");
  }

  tempSolution(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/arende/new");
  }
  reset(){
    window.location = "/";
  }
}
```

App component html:

```
<app-spinner name="global"></app-spinner>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<button (click)="reset()">reset location</button>

<button (click)="locationgo()">location.go(/arende/666)</button>

<button (click)="navigate()">router.navigateByUrl(/arende)</button>

<button (click)="navigateWithLoader()">router.navigateByUrl(/arende/666)</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<button (click)="tempSolution()">temp solution router.navigateByUrl(/arende/new)
</button>
```

Routing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ArendeComponent } from './arende.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'arende', component: ArendeComponent },
  { path: 'arende/:id', component: ArendeComponent },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/arende',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  declarations: [],
  providers:[{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Arende component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-arende',
  template: '<div>arendekomponent id: {{arende.arendeId}}</div>'
})
export class ArendeComponent implements OnInit {
  public arende:Arende = new Arende();
  constructor(
    private router:Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private spinnerService:SpinnerService,
    private restService:RestService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    if(this.route.snapshot.params.id != null){
      if(this.route.snapshot.params.id == "new"){
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/arende");
      }else{
        this.spinnerService.show("global", "Fetching arende");
        this.route.params.switchMap((params:Params) => this.restService.getArende(params["id"]))
        .subscribe(arende => {
          this.spinnerService.hide("global");
          this.arende = arende
        });

        console.log(this.route.params);
      }
    }else{
      this.arende = new Arende();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Instead of using location can't you use the navigateByUrl() there too?

Comment: From what I have seen it will not work cause then it navigates to that url, fetching the recently created object again with loading screen and all and the focus disappears from where he was typing in the form. That is why I was using location.go, only to change the url, not to do a full navigation there.

Answer (score 3):

I found this useful code:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I still cannot navigateByUrl to /arende after using location.go.
But now I can navigateToUrl to / which in turn has a redirect to /arende.
Witout this code it wasn't possible to navigateToUrl to / because the redirect pointed to /arende which was the current state of the router.

Not entirely sure if this code does more than this. I haven't noticed any side effects yet.

Answer (score 2):

As the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#description) state

> Note: it's better to use Router service to trigger route changes. Use Location only if you need to interact with or create normalized URLs outside of routing.

When you use `location.go`, angular's router state is not updated. So what is happening is the router state is initially `/arende`. Then you use location.go, the url is updated to `/arende/666` but the router state is still `/arende`. Therefore once try to use `router.navigateByUrl('/arende')` it does not work because angular still thinks it is on `/arende` so it does not update the url.

You can see this in this forked version of your [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6jrhs?file=app%2Farende.component.ts). I've consoled out the router's url changes in the arende.component. You can see the observable does not fire when using location.go

Comment: Do you know of a way to manually update the state of the router without doing a navgation ? As I wrote in an earlier comment, I cannot use navigateByUrl to navigate to /arende/666 because it will cause a real navigation, it will load my object again, loading-spinner appears and focus is lost from where I was typing in the form, that is why I was using location.go. Is there a way to somehow modify the router state programatically so it thinks I'm at /arende/666 and when trying to navigate to /arende it will do so.

Comment: The closest thing I can come up with is first to location.go. Then to navigateByUrl("arende/new") which senses that the id is "new" and does another navigateByUrl to /arende. It is fast but you still see the /new in the url for a short period of time.

Comment: @ViktorEriksson can you post some of your component code? Are you using something like activatedRoute.paramMap to detect parameter changes?

Comment: I updated my question with a new stackblitz and new info :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ActivedRoute of '@angular/router'  with follwing

```
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
    this.orgId = params.get('id');
    //business logic what changes you want on the page with this new data.
});
```

you have to subscribe each time because url is same only parameter is changing

put this code in your ngOnInit
By snapshot, Reloading do not occur when changing path parameters in url because constructor is not called. But using subscribe it will listen to the changes taking place in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

We can work around this issue by enabling reload on seeing the same URL. Just add

```
{onSameUrlNavigation : 'reload'}
```

to your app module